# Windows Version info the same for Windows 7 and Server 2008

Tags: api, vb6

I'm using VB6 and trying to determine which operating system the software is running on via API call:

GetVersionExA

The problem that I am having is that both Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 return the same value: "6.1.7601"

Can anyone please tell me how to tell the difference of windows 8 and windows 7 using this API, or even another way for VB6?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: you have to correlate the Minor Version with Product Type to tell Vista From W7 From Server 2008 from Server 2008 R2 when using PInvoke

Comment: Or even when working in native code, i.e. the case at hand, VB6, where there is no need for "PInvoke" type mechanisms.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you get the [OSVERSIONINFOEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure (by setting the dwOSVersionInfoSize member of the structure to sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX)) before calling GetVersionEx. As you can see from the link you can use the wProductType member of the struct to help distinguish between OSs.